# Hive view - partitions are not listed

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a internal hive table that is partitioned. I am creating a view on the hive table like this:

```
create view feat_view PARTITIONED ON(partition_dt) AS SELECT col1, partition_dt from features_v2;
```

This works fine. But when I try listing the partitions on the view, I get an empty result:

```
show partitions feat_view;;
+------------+--+
| partition  |
+------------+--+
+------------+--+
```

The base table is partitioned:

```
show partitions features_v2;;
+--------------------------+--+
|        partition         |
+--------------------------+--+
| partition_dt=2018-11-17  |
+--------------------------+--+
```

Is this intended to work? Can I list the partitions on a view just the way I would on a base table?

Answer (score 0):

[From the Apache docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Show), showing view partitions doesn't seem to be supported. You can show partitions of materialized views (Hive 3). See the example at the end of [Create and use a partitioned materialized view](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/using-hiveql/content/hive_create_partitioned_materialized_view.html):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW partition_mv_3 PARTITIONED ON (deptno) AS
SELECT emps.hire_date, emps.deptno FROM emps, emps2
  WHERE emps.deptno = emps2.deptno
  AND emps.deptno > 100 AND emps.deptno < 200;

SHOW PARTITIONS partition_mv_3;
+-------------+
|  partition  |
+-------------+
| deptno=101  |
+-------------+
```